# How to change the icon size and default behaviour of Ubuntu Software Center on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: software-center, customization

I'm having a peculiar problem with Ubuntu Software Center.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the problem?

Comment: what is the problem with image? Do you need more large icon? @Curious Apprentice

Comment: Icons on Software center looking bigger than usual.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It will happen to you machine if you messing with the "hicolor" theme under /usr/share/icons/hicolor

Never mess with its icon sets.

Answer (score 2):

This is how the program has been created. Such details are not easy to change.

If you feel strongly that the behaviour is not optimal, you could consider [reporting a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).